# Java read text file with maze and get all possible paths

Tags: java, algorithm, java-io, fileinputstream, maze

EDIT: I have tried to store the lines character by character into a 2D Array.

However, the problem is to get all possible paths of a maze from **0** to **1** inside of a text file. And the asterisk are the walls or obstacle.

Maze looks like this

```
8,8
********
*0     *
*      *
*  **  *
*  **  *
*      *
*     1*
********
```

I'm not sure if it's achievable to put it into a Two Dimensional Array string. And do a recursion or dynamic programming afterwards.

Note that the only movements allowed is right and down, also the **0** destination could be somewhere on 2nd, 3rd and so on column. Same as **1** destination as well.

Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Achievable? Yes. What have you tried, to start with?

Comment: I've started it by using InputStreamReader where it's reading character by character from a text file until it reached *-1*. Iterating or reading the text file is not the major problem for me I think but I'm wondering if after I've read the file, how can I put it into like a map where I can do *conditional statements*.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to read line by line and then add the lines into an ArrayList

Comment: If I read it line by line, how am I able to check if it's hitting the obstacle? Also the tricky part here is the only movement allowed is right and down. The reason why I'm thinking to have 2D is to increment it as my coordinates.

What in my mind is, to read the text file once, record it as like map so the program will know where the *origin* and *destination* and from there I can increment the *index* and do conditional statements along the run.

But that's what in my mind, I just don't know how to map it as like I have control every index inside of the wall.

Comment: @tuturyokgaming It is very difficult to understand what you are saying, can you get me the question exactly. What is the Input and what is the expected output.

Comment: @VishwaRatna Basically I'm trying to read a text file that has a format inside like the above. First line is the height and width of the wall. The main objective for this program is to get all the possible paths from origin **0** to destination **1* without going through the wall, only allowed to move to right and down. And as you can see there's an obstacle as well inside of the wall where you have to avoid. So the input is the text file, and expected output is only the count of possible paths. Thank you

Comment: is the boundary consistent? i.e. will we always have a uniform boundary of 1*N and N* 1 in all directions or can it vary?

Comment: @scissorHands yes the boundary is consistent, so it is acting like a wall. And the **0** and **1** could be in different places.

Comment: I think you need to create a class for example called as Maze. It has to have a string or string array array and after then you need  to implement a function line getXY(int,int). You can implement more methods like move or endgamedetection in this class.

Comment: You don't want to read stuff from a file and put it into an array. You want someone to implement a path finder. WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED?

Comment: I have already tried to put the line character by character into 2D array, only problem now is to get all possible paths of the maze. Going from 0 to 1 is not a problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this is fairly easy to do:

1. Read the first line of the text file and parse out the dimensions.
2. Create an array of length n.
3. For every (blank) item in the array:

   1. Create a new length-n array as the data.
   2. Parse the next line of the text file as individual characters into the array.

After this, you'll have your n x n data structure to complete your game with.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Map to store this File Seems like a good idea.
While I don't think reading a file character by character would be an issue,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = br.readLine();
```

You have specified the grid dimensions say `(n x n)`
A Simple way I could visualize is by generating unique keys for every coordinate.
More like a Parser method to store Keys in the Map:

```
public String parseCoordinate(int x, int y){
    return x + "" + y;
}

Map<String, Boolean> gridMap = new HashMap<>();
```

So when you read `file` by Characters, you could put parsed coordinates as keys in the map:

```
gridMap.put(parseCoordinate(lineCount, characterCount), line.charAt(characterCount) == '*');
```

Comment: So does this means that every character that stored in HashMap will have their own unique keys right? But the thing is, how will the program know if the coordinates has been gone through? Like calculating all possible paths to destination.

Comment: I actually didn't assume direct operations over the HashMap. It was meant to make it simple and accept sparse maps like the one you specified.
You can try a similar graph structure for traversals. You'll have to do a depth first traversal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the *only problem* you are facing is to decide how to read the file correctly for processing or applying the algorithm to determine the number of unique paths in the given maze.

```
    private static int[][] getMatrixFromFile(File f) throws IOException {
            //Read the input file as a list of String lines
            List<String> lines = Files.lines(f.toPath())
                    //.map(line -> line.substring(1 , line.length() - 1))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            //Get the dimensions of the maze from the first line
            String[] dimensions = lines.get(0).split("\\*");

            //initalize a sub matrix of just the maze dimensions ignoring the walls
            int[][] mat = new int[Integer.valueOf(dimensions[0]) - 2 ][Integer.valueOf(dimensions[1]) - 2];

//for each line in the maze excluding the boundaries , if you encounter a * encode as 0 else 1
            for( int i = 2 ; i < lines.size() - 1  ; i++) {
                String currLine = lines.get(i);
                int j = 0;
                for(char c : currLine.toCharArray())
                        mat[i - 2][j] = (c == '*') ? 0 : 1;
            }

            return mat;
        }
```

With this in place you can now focus on the algorithm for actually traversing the matrix to determine the number of unique paths from top-right to bottom-left.
Having said that  , once you have the above matrix you are not limited to traversing just top-right to bottom-left , rather any arbit point in you maze can serve as start and end points.

If you require help with figuring out the number of unique paths , i can edit to include the bit , but Dynamic programming should help in getting the same.

Comment: Can you please include the bit to figure out the number of unique paths from origin to destination? Also I commented from the above that the **0** and **1** can change the position i.e **0** can be on the [2] or [3] index. I actually want to see it how you do it using DP instead of Recursion (what I am thinking). Cheers!

Comment: The number of unique paths from origin to destination is infinity. You can walk as many circles as you want until you decide to actually go to the goal.

Comment: I don't think it's infinity,  the only move you are allowed to is right and bottom to 
reach destination. Even though the starting point 0 is on 3rd column, it should only move right or bottom and can't go left.

Comment: Ohh, I missed that statement in your question. Wait, it only asks about putting that file into a data structure.

Comment: That is my bad, I have edited my question now.

Answer (score -1):

```
private char[][] maze;

private void read() {
    final InputStream inputStream = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream(INPUT_PATH);
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    try {
        final String header = reader.readLine();
        final String[] tokens = header.split(",");
        if (tokens.length < 2) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid header"); // Use a dedicated exception
        }

        final int dimX = parseInt(tokens[0]);
        final int dimY = parseInt(tokens[1]);
        maze = new char[dimX][dimY];

        for (int i = 0; i < dimY; i++) {
            final String line = reader.readLine();
            maze[i] = line.toCharArray();
        }

    } catch (final IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Now, some assumptions: I assumed the first line contains the declaration of the maze size, so it will be used to initialize the two dimensional array. The other assumption is that you can make use of a char array, but that's pretty easy to change if you want.

From here you can start working on your path finding algorithm.

By the way, this thing you're trying to implement reminds me a lot of [this challenge](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/15) in the Adventofcode challenge series. There are a lot of people discussing their solutions to the challenge, just have a look [in Reddit for instance](https://www.reddit.com/r/adventofcode/comments/a6chwa/2018_day_15_solutions/) and you'll find plenty oh tips on how to go on with your little experiment.

Have fun!

Comment: I actually like this answer, reading the text file and putting into 2D char array. However, I'm having some trouble now to get all possible paths from **0** to **1**. Yes I can get easily from 0 to 1, but I can't think an algorithm to get all possible paths while staying inside of the walls.